# Realtek RTL8188EE Slow Download Rate

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek

This may be a duplicate, but I have been pulling my hair out. I just bought a new Toshiba L75D-A7283, and I really hate Windows 8.1, so I decided to put Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it. Besides a couple of UEFI and graphics issues (which I have resolved), everything works pretty well. However, for some odd reason my Wireless connection has about 50%-75% less download speed than Windows (ranges a lot and can be extremely slow even with a 75mbps service). The upload speed is the same as on Windows however. The LAN port works as well.

I have re-installed Ubuntu about 6-7 times already, trying everything I can find to get this working. I have tried compiling the latest drivers, using ndiswrapper, ignoring IPv6, etc. I don't know what else to do, and I was hoping someone here could direct me. Let me know what information you need and I will provide it via edits.

Reply to Maris' Comments:

> I am currently on Verzion FIOS with a wireless modem. I measured speed
>   between Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine. My desktop and other
>   laptop (Windows 7) get about 65mbps download via wireless, which is
>   the same as this machine on Windows 8.1. The upload is the same across
>   all computers and Operating Systems. In Ubuntu the machine in question
>   gets 80mbps via hardwired connection - the same as Windows. So it is
>   only wireless *download* speed on Ubuntu. My network is not slower in
>   general, just the Toshiba with Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing something similar in terms of low speed downloads with 12.04, out of curiosity - installed 13.10 and the issue was gone, might not be a direct solution for you, but at least a room to experiment.

Another thing I would suggest - please check whether you truly have the latest drivers for your network card. It might be that you need to update them.

Comment: I tried both 12.04 and 13.10. 13.10 yielded the same results for me unfortunately. I used the git project [here](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver.git) and as it is the only one that builds with the newest headers.

Comment: Is there anything we should know about how your network is set up? Any switches, routers, hubs etc? Also, how you measure the speed? Are you connecting to internet resource, or you experience the slowdowns using LAN samba shares or something? Or it doesn't matter and in totally all cases your network is slower?